# Seed method doesn't update database second time after editing it. What to do?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, seed

I create web app using ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC. To add initial data to some tables (for ex. categories) I wrote Seed method and added Migration and updated database successfully (with no errors). Data (with all values added) was seen in the database (SQL Server) after running application. Then I added some other categories in the seed method. This time I didn't see changes (updates) in SQL server after running application and updating database using migration. 
Does Seed work only first time or I can somehow update (increase initial data) the database using Seed? 
This is my Seed method:

```
 public static void Seed(OfferDbContext offerDbContext)
    {
        if (!offerDbContext.Categories.Any())
        {
            Category avto = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Avto"
            };

            Category home = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Ev"
            };

            Category digital = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Digital"
            };

            Category household = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Məişət"
            };

            Category entertainment = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Əyləncə"
            };

            Category furniture = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Mebel"
            };

            Category clothes = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Geyim"
            };

            Category cafe = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Kafe"
            };

            Category food = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Qida"
            };

            Category edu = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Təhsil"
            };

            Category medical = new Category()
            {
                Name = "Tibb"
            };

            Category tourism = new Category()
            {
                Name = "turizm"
            };

            offerDbContext.Categories.AddRange(avto, home, digital, household, entertainment, furniture, clothes, cafe, food, edu, medical, tourism);
            offerDbContext.SaveChanges(); 
        }
    }
```

And Main method in Program.cs where I call that Seed:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (IServiceScope serviceScope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            using(OfferDbContext offerDbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OfferDbContext>())
            {           
                OfferDb.Seed(offerDbContext);
            }
        }

        webHost.Run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the issue is with the below line

```
if (!offerDbContext.Categories.Any())
```

Basically it says if there are no categories then do the adds, there is no else so if there are already categories there it will do nothing.

So maybe throw an else in and if there are already categories just add the new ones,

OR

Potentially you could wrap each of the creates in an if to see if it already exists and if it does not then crate it.